# How do you export/import "index-pattern" types in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

Kibana 4.3 has great features for importing/exporting dashboards, searches, and visualizations. However, the related index-patterns are not contained in the the generated export.json file. When importing an export.json file into another kibana index, Kibana reports errors `Could not locate that index-pattern-field (id: <index-pattern name>)`.

How do you migrate kibana's index-patterns from one Elasticsearch instance to another?

Thanks,

Nathan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/managing-saved-objects.html) (emphasis added)

> Exported dashboards **do not include their associated index patterns**. **Re-create the index patterns manually** before importing saved dashboards to a Kibana instance running on another Elasticsearch cluster.

Since index patterns are saved in the `.kibana` index as well like anything else, what you can do instead of having to recreate them manually, is to save them using an adhoc tool, such as (e.g.) [elasticdump](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump), like this:

```
elasticdump \
  --input=http://host1:9200/.kibana \
  --input-index=.kibana/index-pattern \
  --output=http://host2:9200/.kibana \
  --output-index=.kibana/index-pattern \
  --type=data
```

You could also use [snapshot/restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) on your `.kibana` index

Comment: Why they dont export/import indices as well? (bug or feature)

Comment: There's probably a very good reason not to do it, I'll research and let you know.

Comment: Some more background on this (open) issue: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4288

Comment: According to the latest kibana(6.3) version, the official documentation says that it is a bad idea to use .kibana index since there is a chance that it might break your entire kibana and can lead to dangerous consequences. They have now introduced saved objects API to import/export dashboards from kibana . Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/saved-objects-api.html

Comment: As of Kibana 6.4, you can now import/export index-patterns: https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-6-4-0-released

Comment: Also Kibana 6.4 now introduces a Saved Objects API which is safer to use than directly writing to the `.kibana` index: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.4/saved-objects-api.html

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to migrate an AWS elasticsearch instance from one cluster to a new one... (hope this helps...)

I had a similar problem to the OP (I was trying to migrate data from one AWS Elasticsearch instance to a new one, using the [AWS instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html)). 
For some reason, restoration of the cluster would fail with the following cryptic error.

```
"cannot restore index [.kibana] because it's open"
```

After much googling and head scratching, I decided it would be easier to migrate the .kibana index separately to the rest of the indices

I tried @Val's awesome suggestion to use [elasticdump](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump) , however, @Val's example didn't work for me.

I ended up basing my command on the example from the elasticdump readme,

```
  elasticdump \
  --input=https://search-some-prod-instance.ap-southeast-2.es.amazonaws.com/.kibana \
  --output=https://search-other-prod-instance.ap-southeast-2.es.amazonaws.com/.kibana \
  --type=data
```

After running this command, the indices from my old kibana were now available in the new kibana. (finally :p)

nb: I also used the kibana "management->saved objects export / import" to migrate my visualisations, searches, dashboards, etc...

Comment: `"cannot restore index [.kibana] because it's open" ` says that you need to `close` the `.kibana` index before you can restore. Because you cannot restore into an open index

Comment: @SandeepKanabar - yeah, realised that.
Have you got the command available to close an open index on an AWS hosted Elasticsearch? Or a reference/link to the docs?

Comment: `POST <index_name>/_close` from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/indices-open-close.html

Comment: awesome thanks @SandeepKanabar , I'll work that into my backup strategy :)