# Programmatically Import Dashboards Kibana

Tags: api, elasticsearch, logging, kibana

I'm looking for a way to import dashboards programmatically into Kibana 5.0. 
I'm running an ELK stack inside of a docker container for ad hoc log analysis. I'm currently running a fourth container that waits for the logstash service to listen on localhost:5000, and then pumps logs into it. I want to expand this script to pump in dashboards. I can configure the dashboards I want in Kibana and then 'export everything' into a nice json blob. Is there an 'import everything' endpoint for this blob that I can tap to upload my predefined dashboards? I want to give this to team members and have the whole thing be automated (instead of manually uploading the json file in 'management --> saved objects'). Thanks.

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423439/how-do-you-export-import-index-pattern-types-in-kibana/37427311#37427311

Answer (score 0):

You can use elasticsearch-dump - An open source tool from taskrabbit for moving and saving indicies: https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump